# Learning AJAX filling form

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, post

I'm creating check box which creates new log using AJAX. It fills info and automatically presses button to "create' So far i created this, but it doesn't change hour value, what am I doing wrong?

```
$canEdit = getPermission('tasks', 'edit', $a['task_id']);
$canViewLog = getPermission('task_log', 'view', $a['task_id']);
if ($canEdit) {
    $s .= ("\n\t\t".'<a href="#">'
           . "\n\t\t\t".'<input type="checkbox" onclick="createlog()" alt="' . $AppUI->_('Check') 
           . '" border="0" width="12" height="12" />' . "\n\t\t</a>");
}
$s .= "\n\t</td>";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function createlog(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'?m=tasks&amp;a=view&amp;tab=1&amp;task_id=' . $a['task_id'] .'',
        data: {url: $('task_log_hours').value(8)
    })
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have not closed the curly brackets in the below line:

```
data: {url: $('task_log_hours').value(8)
```

It should be like this:

```
data: {url: $('task_log_hours').value(8) }
```